# Why do we use specific orbital energy and specific angular momentum?

Tags: mass, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

In the derivation for vis-viva equation
$$v^2 = GM \left({ 2 \over r} - {1 \over a}\right),$$
[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis-viva_equation) they use specific quantities such as specific energy and specific angular momentum but I don't understand what value this provides.

Suppose you have only two bodies, then you will have only one mass 'factor' to multiply with. So, what use does this have? I could see this being useful for multiple bodies but definitely this concept would not be applicable if we had three body problem or greater

Comment: Exactly what does this formula represent, and where did the 2 come from?

Comment: I saw it derivation of vis-viva equation

Answer (score 1):

Because of the [equivalence principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle), the mass of a small body (such as a satellite) does not affect its motion in the gravitational field due to a large body (such as that due to planet). Classically, gravitational accelerations are independent of mass, as the mass terms in Newton's Second Law and the Law of Universal gravitation cancel. Therefore, in orbital mechanics it's often more convenient to analyse problems in terms of [specific orbital energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_orbital_energy), rather than include mass terms which don't affect the results.

Your version of the vis-viva equation simply states:
$$\frac{KE}{2 m} = - \frac{PE}{2 m} + \frac{TE}{2 m} $$
where KE, PE, and TE are the kinetic, potential, and total energy respectively. This represents motion in the gravitational field of a single body. Extension to multiple bodies just involves adding more potential energy terms and accepting that $a$ no longer has a nice geometric interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Specific energy (rarely used) would be energy/mass (J/kg). They are setting m = 1, or they could just cancel m from each side of the equation.